# Flutter pass functions to items for list view builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

What I wanna do is that I have  a ListView with icons and stuff, they are like little shortcuts for the most used functions in the app.

```
    List _shortcuts = [
    {
      'name': 'HORN',
      'icon': Icons.circle_outlined,
      'selection': false,
      'func': (String dummy) {
        // do something
        print('I did it!' + dummy);
      },
    },
  ].toList();
```

So my question is... is it possible to call each items unique function in the Listviews builder method?

Something like `_shortcuts[i]['func']('wow')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class that will be used in your `_shortcuts` list. See the example below:

```dart
// The ShortCut class.
class ShortCut {
  final String name;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool selection;
  final void Function(String) func;

  const ShortCut({
    required this.name,
    required this.icon,
    required this.selection,
    required this.func,
  });
}
```

This class can be used within a widget and the function can be accessed from within the builder method of the `ListView` widget as follows:

```dart
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  /// The is your list with custom shortcuts.
  final _shortCuts = <ShortCut>[
    ShortCut(
      name: 'HORN',
      icon: Icons.circle_outlined,
      selection: false,
      func: (String dummy) {
        // do something
        print('I did it!' + dummy);
      },
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _shortCuts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final _shortCut = _shortCuts[index];

        // Call the function here.
        _shortCut.func('dummy');

        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I hope that this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _short = [
  {
     'name': 'HORN',
      'icon': "Icons.circle_outlined",
      'selection': false,
      'func': (String dummy) { 
       print('I did it! \t' + dummy);
      },
  }
];
  
_short[0]["func"]("hello");
    
}
```

Hopefully, this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Got this:

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'new _ShortCutsState.<anonymous closure>'
Receiver: Closure: () => Null
Tried calling: new _ShortCutsState.<anonymous closure>("hello")
Found: new _ShortCutsState.<anonymous closure>() => Null

Answer (score -1):

I think this should be done in php. Dart can't do that.

Comment: It's possible, you should have a look at my code snippet.